# Cabal problems installing music-suite

Tags: haskell, installation, cabal, lilypond

I am trying to install music-suite for use with Haskell via cabal. Following the instructions, here http://music-suite.github.io/docs/ref/ , which suggest downloading Lilypond, I entered `cabal install lilypond` and downloaded it successfully.

Problems began when I tried to install music-suite via cabal. Here is what happened:

```
mm$ cabal install music-suite
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: music-suite-1.9.0 (user goal)
[__1] trying: musicxml2-1.9.0 (dependency of music-suite)
[__2] trying: base-4.11.1.0/installed-4.1... (dependency of musicxml2)
[__3] trying: music-score-1.9.0 (dependency of music-suite)
[__4] trying: vector-space-points-0.2.1.2 (dependency of music-score)
[__5] next goal: transformers (dependency of music-score)
[__5] rejecting: transformers-0.5.5.0/installed-0.5..., transformers-0.5.6.2,
transformers-0.5.5.0, transformers-0.5.4.0, transformers-0.5.2.0,
transformers-0.5.1.0, transformers-0.5.0.1, transformers-0.5.0.0 (conflict:
music-score => transformers>=0.4.3.0 && <0.5)
[__5] rejecting: transformers-0.4.3.0 (conflict:
base==4.11.1.0/installed-4.1..., transformers => base>=2 && <4.9)
[__5] rejecting: transformers-0.4.2.0, transformers-0.4.1.0,
transformers-0.3.0.0, transformers-0.2.2.1, transformers-0.2.1.0,
transformers-0.2.0.0, transformers-0.1.4.0, transformers-0.1.3.0,
transformers-0.1.1.0, transformers-0.1.0.1, transformers-0.0.1.0,
transformers-0.0.0.0, transformers-0.5.6.1, transformers-0.5.6.0,
transformers-0.5.3.1, transformers-0.5.3.0, transformers-0.5.0.2,
transformers-0.4.0.0, transformers-0.2.2.0, transformers-0.1.0.0 (conflict:
music-score => transformers>=0.4.3.0 && <0.5)
[__5] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, music-score, transformers)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: music-score, base, transformers,
music-suite, musicxml2, vector-space-points
```

What exactly has gone wrong? How can I resolve this problem?

I tried to install it via stack, but this message came up:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for music-suite-1.9.0:
abcnotation must match ==1.9.0, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version
            is 1.9.0)
lilypond must match ==1.9.0, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version
         is 1.9.0)
music-articulation must match ==1.9.0, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching
                   version is 1.9.0)
music-dynamics must match ==1.9.0, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version
               is 1.9.0)
music-dynamics-literal must match ==1.9.0, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching
                       version is 1.9.0)
music-parts must match ==1.9.0, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version
            is 1.9.0)
music-pitch must match ==1.9.0, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version
            is 1.9.0)
music-pitch-literal must match ==1.9.0, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching
                    version is 1.9.0)
music-preludes must match ==1.9.0, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version
               is 1.9.0)
music-score must match ==1.9.0, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version
            is 1.9.0)
musicxml2 must match ==1.9.0, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version
          is 1.9.0)
needed since music-suite is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Consider trying 'stack solver', which uses the cabal-install solver to attempt to find some working build
configuration. This can be convenient when dealing with many complicated constraint errors, but results may be
unpredictable.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps
in /Users/mm/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml:

- abcnotation-1.9.0
- lilypond-1.9.0
- music-articulation-1.9.0
- music-dynamics-1.9.0
- music-dynamics-literal-1.9.0
- music-parts-1.9.0
- music-pitch-1.9.0
- music-pitch-literal-1.9.0
- music-preludes-1.9.0
- music-score-1.9.0
- musicxml2-1.9.0
```

I had added all these dependencies (which are also listed here http://hackage.haskell.org/package/music-suite-1.9.0/dependencies), however
I receive `The same package name is used in multiple local packagesbase-orphans used in:
- PLIndex "base-orphans-0.8"
- PLIndex "base-orphans-0.3.3"` when I type `stack install music-suite` at the terminal.

When I remove one of these dependencies, I get a message asking for them to be restored, and I also get the following errors:

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

```
 In the dependencies for cassava-0.4.4.0:
base-4.12.0.0 from stack configuration does not match >=4.5 && <4.9  (latest matching version is 4.8.2.0)
 needed due to music-suite-1.9.0 -> cassava-0.4.4.0

  In the dependencies for comonad-4.3:
base-4.12.0.0 from stack configuration does not match >=0 && <0 
 needed due to music-suite-1.9.0 -> comonad-4.3

 In the dependencies for directory-1.2.7.1:
base-4.12.0.0 from stack configuration does not match >=4.5 && <4.11  (latest matching version is 4.10.1.0)
 needed due to music-suite-1.9.0 -> directory-1.2.7.1

 In the dependencies for monadplus-1.4.2:
base-4.12.0.0 from stack configuration does not match >=4 && <4.11  (latest matching version is 4.10.1.0)
 needed due to music-suite-1.9.0 -> monadplus-1.4.2

 In the dependencies for music-score-1.9.0:
base-orphans-0.8 from stack configuration does not match >=0.1 && <0.4  (latest matching version is 0.3.3)
 needed due to music-suite-1.9.0 -> music-score-1.9.0

 In the dependencies for process-1.2.3.0:
base-4.12.0.0 from stack configuration does not match >=4.4 && <4.9  (latest matching version is 4.8.2.0)
 needed due to music-suite-1.9.0 -> process-1.2.3.0

 In the dependencies for transformers-0.4.3.0:
base-4.12.0.0 from stack configuration does not match >=2 && <4.9  (latest matching version is 4.8.2.0)
 needed due to music-suite-1.9.0 -> transformers-0.4.3.0

 In the dependencies for vector-space-points-0.2.1.2:
base-4.12.0.0 from stack configuration does not match >=4.0 && <4.12  (latest matching version is 4.11.1.0)
 needed due to music-suite-1.9.0 -> vector-space-points-0.2.1.2

 Some different approaches to resolving this:

   * Set 'allow-newer: true' to ignore all version constraints and build anyway.

   * Consider trying 'stack solver', which uses the cabal-install solver to attempt to find some working build
configuration. This can be convenient when dealing with many complicated constraint errors, but results may be
unpredictable.
```

Comment: By using `stack` instead of `cabal`, for example.

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz: I have edited the question. I tried via stack, but it didn't work, and I don't understand what the recommended action is asking me to do.

Comment: it's just asking to add those dependencies in the stack.yaml

Comment: @Lorenzo: I tried adding those dependencies, and then when I write `stack install music-suite` I get `The same package name is used in multiple local packages

base-orphans used in:
- PLIndex "base-orphans-0.8"
- PLIndex "base-orphans-0.3.3"`.     Which do I get rid of?

Comment: I'd say the oldest one - 0.3.3(?)

Comment: @Lorenzo: Then it tells me to add `base-orphans-0.3.3` again

Comment: @Lorenzo: I have edited my question with further problems that arise when adding dependencies.

Comment: Try `allow-newer: true` in your stack.yaml

Comment: @user65526 What do you get from `cabal --version`?

Comment: Quite frankly, I think this is a problem with the package versioning itself so the best way to proceed with this one is to create a pull request or rather just use stack when building the source by also migrating everything to stack

Comment: @Lorenzo: it still comes up with the same errors.

Comment: @Alec: `cabal-install version 2.2.0.0
compiled using version 2.2.0.1 of the Cabal library`

Comment: @Adrian Legaspi: what kind of pull request, and how do I create one? What does it mean to build the source by migrating everything to stack and using stack in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The payload in your cabal error is here (I have editorialized a bit, replacing some very repetitive stuff with `<...>`):

```
[__5] next goal: transformers (dependency of music-score)
[__5] rejecting: transformers-0.5.5.0, <...> (conflict: music-score => transformers>=0.4.3.0 && <0.5)
[__5] rejecting: transformers-0.4.3.0 (conflict: base==4.11.1.0/installed-4.1..., transformers => base>=2 && <4.9)
[__5] rejecting: transformers-0.4.2.0, <...> (conflict: music-score => transformers>=0.4.3.0 && <0.5)
```

Lines 2 and 4 together say that, of all the possible available versions of the `transformers` package, *only* version `0.4.3.0` meets the version bounds in `music-core`'s constraints. Line 3 says that `transformers-0.4.3.0` demands `base <4.9`, and your version of `base` is too new to meet that constraint.

So far so good, just standard constraint solving, and a summary of what has gone wrong in the constraint set cabal sees. Now for some high-level interpretation that cabal isn't qualified to give you.

`base` is the deepest, most hard-wired library; it comes with GHC and can't be replaced, so your only choice for changing `base` versions is installing a different version of GHC. There is, unfortunately, no principled connection between `base` version number and GHC version number, though there is a table [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package). Consulting that table, we see that GHC 7.10.3 was the last one to ship a `base` version under 4.9.

Therefore, to get past this problem and on to the next problem, you should install a version of GHC which is at least as old as 7.10.3, and then tell cabal to use it when performing its constraint solving. This latter you can do either by making the new (old) GHC be the first one on your PATH, or by using cabal's `-w` flag to specify exactly which compiler to use, as in:

```
cabal install music-suite -w ghc-7.10.3
```

Comment: How can I install an older version of GHC? How do I then open the older version (version 7.10.3), and open the newer version at the terminal? Would there be any conflicts or problems from having two versions?

Comment: @user65526 For question one, I trust you can find GHC's website with Google. For question two, I included instructions in the answer already. For question three, GHC's installer is generally careful to install versioned names of each executable, though it will reset the non-versioned name to point at the most-recently-installed versioned name; I use [this script](https://gist.github.com/dmwit/1d4af1c62fc2ef33cfd7994bc022c2be) if I want to revert to a different default version after an installation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that music-suite hasn't been updated for some years and can't be directly built with the latest GHC releases.

Hopefully, we can use "stack" which is a tool that allows you to specify which GHC and which packages to use. However I haven't been able to find a build plan working with the music-suite packages on Hackage, so let's build them from sources:

1) Install stack (instructions are on https://haskellstack.org)

2) Optional: create a new package with `stack new mypackage` (or you can use your own package)

3) In your package folder, create or edit the "stack.yaml" file so that it contains:

```
resolver: lts-13.8

packages:
- .
- music-suite
- music-parts
- music-score
- music-articulation
- music-pitch
- music-dynamics
- lilypond
- musicxml2
- monadplus

extra-deps:
- average-0.6.1
- prettify-1.0
- data-interval-1.3.0
- extended-reals-0.2.3.0
- positive-0.4.1
- type-unary-0.3.2
- vector-space-points-0.2.1.2
- applicative-numbers-0.1.3
- ty-0.1.7
- reverse-apply-2.0.1
- roman-numerals-0.5.1.5

allow-newer: true

ghc-options:
   "music-score": -XUndecidableInstances
```

4) In your package folder, fetch and fix music-suite with the following commands:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/music-suite/lilypond
git clone https://github.com/music-suite/music-suite
git clone https://github.com/music-suite/music-score
git clone https://github.com/music-suite/music-dynamics
git clone https://github.com/music-suite/music-parts
git clone https://github.com/music-suite/music-pitch
git clone https://github.com/music-suite/music-articulation
git clone https://github.com/music-suite/musicxml2
git clone https://github.com/hanshoglund/monadplus

echo "instance Semigroup (Partial a b) where (<>) = mplus" >> monadplus/src/Control/Monad/Plus.hs

echo "instance Semigroup RhythmContext where (<>) = mappend" >> music-score/src/Music/Score/Internal/Quantize.hs
echo "instance Semigroup CrescDim where (<>) = mappend" >> music-score/src/Music/Score/Export/DynamicNotation.hs
echo "instance Semigroup DynamicNotation where (<>) = mappend" >> music-score/src/Music/Score/Export/DynamicNotation.hs
echo "instance Semigroup Slur where (<>) = mappend" >> music-score/src/Music/Score/Export/ArticulationNotation.hs
echo "instance Semigroup Mark where (<>) = mappend" >> music-score/src/Music/Score/Export/ArticulationNotation.hs
echo "instance Semigroup ArticulationNotation where (<>) = mappend" >> music-score/src/Music/Score/Export/ArticulationNotation.hs
echo "instance Semigroup (ScScore a) where (<>) = mappend" >> music-score/src/Music/Score/Export/SuperCollider.hs
echo "instance Semigroup SystemBar where (<>) = mappend" >> music-score/src/Music/Score/Export2/StandardNotation.hs
echo "instance Semigroup StaffInfo where (<>) = mappend" >> music-score/src/Music/Score/Export2/StandardNotation.hs
echo "instance Semigroup Chord where (<>) = mappend" >> music-score/src/Music/Score/Export2/StandardNotation.hs
echo "instance Semigroup MovementInfo where (<>) = mappend" >> music-score/src/Music/Score/Export2/StandardNotation.hs
echo "instance Semigroup WorkInfo where (<>) = mappend" >> music-score/src/Music/Score/Export2/StandardNotation.hs
```

5) Now you can build the whole thing with `stack build`

---

A simpler solution would be to ask for the release of newer music-suite packages on Hackage.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your steps 1) - 4), but when I tried `stack build` I got `$ stack build
Error parsing targets: The specified targets matched no packages.
Perhaps you need to run 'stack init'?
mm$ stack init
Looking for .cabal or package.yaml files to use to init the project.`

Comment: Are you sure to execute commands 3 and 4 in a package folder containing a .cabal file?